# Uniform infinitesimality Condition and convergence in distribution to Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding Uniform Infinitesimality Condition and weak convergence to Gaussian distribution.

Suppose $(X_{n,i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is an triangular array of independent random variables satisfying the uniform infinitesimality condition:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}P(|X_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0$$
Further suppose that the distribution of $A_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{n,i}$ converges in distribution to a limit $\mu$. Show that $\mu$ is Gaussian if and only if ${\lim_{n\to \infty}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(|X_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0.$

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about supposing $X_{n,i} = \frac{T_{n,i}}{n^2}$, where $T_{n,i}$ are independent exponential random variables with the parameter 1, such that we have $E(T_{n,i}) = 1$ and $P(T_{n,i} \geq x) = e^{-x}$

Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{n,i} \geq \epsilon) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(T_{n,i} \geq n^2\epsilon) = ne^{-n^2\epsilon}$, which converge to 0 as $n$ approaches $+\infty, \forall \epsilon > 0$

However, when we look at $A_n = \sum_{i=i}^{n}X_{n,i}$, we find that $A_n= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n T_{n,i}}{n^2}$, which converge to 0 in $L^{1}$ since $E|A_n| = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(T_{n,i})}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$. So $A_n$ converge in distribution to a limit $\mu$, which is the constant 0.

Comment: If $A_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$, how to show $A_n$ converge in distribution to $0$? Can you give some hint here? Thank you very much!!

Comment: I got it. Just use the strong law of large numbers.